# Usage of "ever" in a negative statement

Tags: grammar, word-usage, negation

I know that "ever" can be used to express the strengthened negation but would it work like that?

> I created a session but nobody ever joined.

Is it possible? It does not sound right to me. If not, what does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example you have given, "ever" serves two purposes. It does act to emphasise the negative as you have suggested.  It also adds a temporal dimension to the sentence.

If you consider your sentence without "ever" it gives the impression of a one time event:

> I created a session but nobody joined.

Whereas your sentence indicates that this has been happening for a substantial length of time and implies that it is unlikely to change:

> I created a session but nobody ever joined.

Answer (score 4):

*Ever* is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) (NPI), and is in fact a [suppletive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion) temporal form of *any*, the most sensitive NPI.

English has various NPI combined forms with *any*:

- *She won't tell **anyone/anybody**.*
- *She's right about him, **anyway/anyhow**.*
- *I don't see her **anywhere**.*

But there's no word **anywhen* -- we use *ever* instead:

- **He hasn't met her anywhen.*
- *He hasn't met her ever.*
- *He hasn't ever met her.*

Just like we use *both* instead of **all two*, or *went* instead of **goed*.

So it's an NPI time term, meaning "at any time", and it has a more variable syntax than *anywhere* does, since it preferentially precedes the verb, instead of being tacked on at the end.

- *I don't see her anywhere.*
- **I don't anywhere see her.*
- *I don't see her ever.*
- *I don't ever see her.*

In the sentence in question

- *I created a session but nobody ever joined.*

*ever* is used exactly right. The negative trigger *nobody* (cf *anybody*) licenses the use of NPIs, and the NPI *ever* is deployed between it and the negated verb. In terms of time, *nobody ever joined* says that, in the time since the creation of the session until now, there was no person who joined the session that was created (note that the direct object of *joined* has been deleted, but is clearly implied). Which is what you intended to say, I gather.

Comment: since the creation until now - how come, it is past simple. I thought that would need to be present perfect to express what you said.

Comment: No, though it's possible. You could have said _nobody has ever joined._ Though that _has_ would normally be contracted to /z/ and frequently deleted in speech, so they're almost indistinguishable in practice. As in any language, there are many many many ways to say anything. Rules you get in textbooks are almost always wrong in what they tell you about English tenses and their usages. If a textbook tells you that English has a Future tense marked with _will_, for instance, throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon the tense. Since I created the session before holding it, I would have used the past perfect and written:

> I had created a session, but nobody ever came.

And, yes, there is a comma before but.