# "Nobody ever joined" vs "Nobody joined at all"

Tags: grammar, differences, negation, negative-polarity-items

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage of “ever” in a negative statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73695/usage-of-ever-in-a-negative-statement)

Yesterday I read a discussion here and I still cannot figure it out. What is the difference between the following:

> Nobody ever joined

and

> Nobody joined at all

I assume both express that nobody joined, not a single person but I still tend to use "ever" only with present perfect and cannot feel the difference here.

Comment: No it is NOT a duplicate as this is about difference betweeb "at all" and "ever" in negative statement

Comment: Probably in "Nobody joined at all", "at all" adds more emphasis, since it is a very common intensifier with negative expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Nobody **ever** joined"* emphasises that nobody joined throughout some [extended] period of time. As John Lawler says, *"ever"* here is a temporal (time-related) [Negative Polarity Item](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item).

By contrast, *"nobody joined at all"* (or perhaps, *"nobody at all joined"*) emphasises that *not a single person joined*. Time isn't relevant - it could be in the context of a one-off membership offer lasting only one day. Here, *"at all"* (also an NPI) just intensifies the negation already conveyed by *"nobody"*.

---

Possibly just my personal opinion, but I think sometimes there's a shift in nuance if the verb comes between *"nobody"* and *"at all"*. For example, to me,

> *"Nobody at all argues"* emphasises that of all the people who might argue, none in fact do.
>
> *"Nobody argues at all"* emphasises that of all the things people might be doing, they're definitely not doing anything that could be described as "arguing". That perspective doesn't mean anything (at all!) with a verb like *"join"*, which is why I think putting the verb at the end is better for OP's context.

Comment: Right on, bro. I see you been readin the book.

Comment: @John Lawler: Haha ty. Your answer is the real "nitty-gritty". Until I read it, I had no conscious awareness of the fact that *"at all"* normally only intensifies *existing* negations. So, for example, concerned mother could say to sickly child off its food: *"Will you **not** eat a bite at all?"*. Omitting *"not"* there sounds dialectal to me (possibly "pseudo-dialect"; for all I know nobody at all ever says that! :)

Comment: That's the point, and why I've been pointing to [that list](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) of NPIs and triggers so often. Negative Polarity was only discovered around 1970; it certainly isn't anything one learned about in fifth grade.

Comment: There you go! It's not like nobody ever used NPIs before they were "discovered". So re [discusion elsewhere](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/), maybe ELU collectively will discover some previously-unrecognised characteristic of English, and popularise it through the tagging system here! Anyway, I'm seriously thinking *Negative Polarity Item* should be a tag, even if others eventually decide it's just an excessively specific form of the existing tag [negation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negation)

Comment: Given the splits in other labels, I'd be glad to see some accurate subdivisions. [Negation and Negative Polarity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) are certainly related, but not at all the same thing.

Comment: I *think* I've just created my first-ever tag on ELU! Not every question currently tagged *negation* should also be tagged *negative-polarity-items*. But this one obviously should be, and by virtue of me editing it to add that new name to the existing "tags" list, it now exists for others to select and use elsewhere. Perhaps you could check [my first attempt at a tag wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/negative-polarity-items/info), and correct/improve as appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have tag wiki privileges yet, apparently. A link to the [NPI list](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), and perhaps one to the [Encyclopedia article](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), might be useful, though I really dunno what might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

*Ever* is a **Negative Polarity Item** (*'NPI'*; see [this recent post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73724/15299) for explanation and behavior).

*At all* is also an NPI, but it's not temporal like *ever*, it's not a variant of *any* (like *ever*), and it has quite a different function.

*At all* is an NPI **intensifier**, referring to -- and emphasizing -- **total** negation of whatever is being negated, rather than referring to the extent of time when something **could** have happened, but didn't, like *ever*.

- *Nobody joined at all.*
- *Nobody at all showed up for the party.*
- *Nobody ever showed up for the party.*
- **Somebody joined at all.*
- **Somebody ever showed up for the party.*

There is no logical difference between a negative with and without *at all*:
If *he didn't show up for the party **at all***, then *he didn't show up for the party*; and vice versa.

I think (and here I'm guessing) that *at all* is a variant of the Minimal Direct Object NPI structure: *eat a bite, drink a drop, give a damn, sleep a wink.*

- If you *don't eat a bite*, then you *don't eat anything*, you *don't eat at all*
- If you don't even *sleep a wink*, then you don't *sleep at all*.

Etc. *At all* has some interesting syntactic properties; for one thing it can occur by itself, but it plays well with other NPIs (boldfaced) and frequently appears with them, as in [this example](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/npislands.html):

- *The candidates never mentioned it at all.*  (Neg trigger = *never*)
- *The candidates never said **anything** about it at all.*
- *I'm surprised he showed up at all.*  (Neg trigger = *surprised*)
- *I'm surprised he **ever** mentioned it at all*.
- *They kept her from leaving at all.* (Neg trigger = *keep from*)
- *They kept her from **budging** at all.*

Comment: The wikipedia articles on [downward entailment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downward_entailment) and [veridicality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veridicality) have a reference to a paper, "Licensing and sensitivity in polarity items: from downward entailment to nonveridicality", that may be relevant also.

Comment: See [this article](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) for the origins of the downward-entailment metaphor, among others used for NPIs.